# How to dealing rest api with huge data using mySQL, Django, vueJS

Tags: mysql, django, api, rest, vue.js

Circumstance:

1. VueJS request to Django for get all Data where in mySQL.
2. Load mySQL-data (The files-ize is approximately 8GB as CSV) with Django will do.
3. Django make response with this data and send it back to vueJS.

The problem is 3.
Eventually the Front-End(vueJS) has to not only achieves all the data without loss but also show it to user.

Is there some way to make it faster?

In my opinion, API Chaining way is a bit useful like bellow.
Request)

```
let amout_rows = 20
axios.get("url/" + amout_rows)
.then((res) => {
    if (res.data.status === 200) {
        axios.get("url/" + amout_rows+20) {
            .then((res) => {.. continues}.catch(()=>{})
        }
    }
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err)
})
```

Django

> collect data from mySQL
> response(data=data, status=200)

In this opinion occurs API(transaction) frequently so I think it is very bad for solve the issue that
give all the data to Front-End.

I don't know any other idea and logics.

It will be very helpful if there is other way thanks.

Comment: is it that necessary to display all of the data directly?

Comment: or you can use recursive strategy, better than chaining like above

Comment: @kusiaga Hello kusiaga. First of all, yes I totally with you. I am working with doubt for "Is it really necessary?" but however, regardless of this doubt, my senior wants to implement it eagerly so I have to do it no matter what. It is very sad and confuses me. Therefore, I really wish to know what is your "recursive strategy" is.

Comment: You need to show 8GB of data to a user??  Sounds like an insomnia cure!

Comment: @RickJames Hello there. Yes indeed. Can't deny :)

Comment: @Lucas.Park - Then, is it going at nearly the network speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know If it gonna work, but the concept is like this. You need to decide in what condition you function will stop the recursion and in what condition your recursion will keep running.

You can modify as your needs.

```
async init () {
    try {
        let result = await axios.get('/someurl');
        if (result.data.status == 200) {
            this.someData = result.data.someDataFromServer
            // do execute function recursively
            this.init()
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status != 200) {
            // what you gonna do if the recursive stopped
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your specific logic code. :)
I compromised with my senior.

Answer (score 0):

I compromised with my senior.

I tried and showed him with two different results.

A way)

collected data from DB via python - mysqlClient connection

FRONT-END

```
axios.get("url/")
.then((res) => {
    if (res.data.status === 200) {
    data_table_HDR = res.data.HDR
    data_table_body = res.data.body
    }
}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

BACKEND

```
connection = mysqldb.connectoin(connection_info ID,PW,HOST,PORT etc..)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.excute(f"select * from certain_table")
data = cursor.fetchall()
resp_data = {HDR: data[0], body: data[1]}
response(data=data, status=200)
```

In this A way, well... the browser's screen was white with "No response" and did not work properly so had to kill the process by window's system management.
And also python IDE which I used pycharm IDE, it was didn't worked properly like no response so I had to kill it too.
I showed him with this symptom(phenomenon) then surprisingly his react was kinda happy.
And then he suggested other way as below, I'll call it as "B way".

B way)

FRONT-END

```
const isInit = False

do_data_collect() {
    if (isInit === False) {
        this.init()
    } else {
        this.nextStep(user_input_integer)
    }
}
init(user_input_integer) {
    limit_value = user_input_integer
    axios.get("url/" + limit_value)
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === 200) {
            data_table_HDR = res.data.HDR
            data_table_body = res.data.body
            isInit = True
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
}
nextStep(user_input_integer) {
    limit_value = user_input_integer
    offset = limit_value + limit_value

    axios.get({
    url: "url",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        token
    },
    params: {
        limit_value: limit_value,
        offset: offset
    })
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === 200) {
            data_table_body.append(res.data.body)
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
}
```

BACKEND

```
limit_value = request.get("limit_value")
offset = request.get("offset")
connection = mysqldb.connectoin(connection_info ID,PW,HOST,PORT etc..)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.excute(f"select * from certain_table limit {limit_value} offset {offset}")
data = cursor.fetchall()
resp_data = {HDR: data[0], body: data[1]}
response(data=data, status=200)
```

In this B way,
It works like ping-pong.
The Front-End requests with amount limitation & offset.
And the Back-End performs Read file or get data from DB.
Front-End receives response and show it result as pop-up(Dialog) and when user
scrolls down via mouse then API occurs again and it loops until when it gets to no more
data.

In this way, it was no browser and IDE down issues.
However, the data_table_body appends next data it become contains huge amount of data
so that it occurs memory problems.

Consequently, show all the data of huge data to END-USER is not a good idea.
Give 'em data as a file-download will be better I think.

And am I along? living this working-drama in this world?
Implement and Testing and Compares.. every time... :(